Custom CodeQL query in Azure DevOps in yaml pipeline gives error: No queries defined for javascript
I want to run custom codeql queries for Advanced Security in Azure DevOps (this is a feature that is now available in Azure DevOps not only GitHub).  The built in default queries like security-and-quality works fine. I run them as batch at night.
But I am now building a new separate pipeline that will also run at night as a batch. With it I want to run a few custom queries looking for specific not wanted pattern in this rather large JavaScript git repository.
All of this is stored and run in Azure DevOps Services. I have started with a simple find all ToDo codeql query to get thing going. But I get this error, that I cant find in the documentation or Troubleshooting code scanning faq , or see anyone else have had before:
/opt/hostedtoolcache/CodeQL/2.17.2/x64/codeql/codeql database init --codescanning-config=/home/vsts/work/1/s/.azuredevops/customcodeql/customconfig.yaml --db-cluster /home/vsts/work/_temp/advancedsecurity.codeql/d --source-root=/home/vsts/work/1/s --language=javascript --calculate-baseline
A fatal error occurred: No queries defined for javascript
##[warning] Error running the 'database init' CodeQL command for javascript (2)
##[error]Error running the 'database init' CodeQL command for javascript (2)

====================================================================================================
Analyzing CodeQL execution results.
CodeQL analysis finished with exit code 2.

I have a yaml pipeline with the tasks
AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1 ,  AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Autobuild@1 and AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Analyze@1  .
The task AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1 points to a codeqlconfig yaml file and in this file I point to a simple todo codeql query. This is afaik how it has to be done according to the documentation I have read eg: Analysis with custom queries .
I once wrote the wrong path the codeql query. Then I got the error message: A fatal error occurred: ./azuredevops/customcodeql/todos.ql is not a .ql file, .qls file, a directory, or a query pack specification.
I corrected the path (added . infront so it became ./.azuredevops....) and no longer got the cant find file type of error, so I assume it finds the file now.
But now I get this other error: "No queries defined for javascript" so assume that it finds my todos.ql but it does not work anyway.
Here are the three files that I use:
Here is the todo.ql taken from the examples :
/**
 * @id js/javascript/todocomment
 * @name TODO_comments
 * @description Finds comments containing the word TODO
 * @kind problem
 * @problem.severity recommendation
 * @tags comment
 *       TODO
 */
import javascript

from Comment c
where c.getText().regexpMatch("(?si).*\\bTODO\\b.*")
select c

Here is the codeql customconfig.yaml :
name: "Run custom queries"
disable-default-queries: true
queries:
  - name: TODO_comments
    uses: ./.azuredevops/customcodeql/todos.ql
paths:
  - src 
paths-ignore: 
  - '**/node_modules'
  - '**/*.test.js'
query-filters:
 - include:
    kind: problem

Here is part of the yaml pipeline that is run in Azure DevOps as a batch job.
Ehe error occur on the task AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1 version 1.1.262 after about 7 seconds
- stage: Analyze_Custom_CQL
  jobs:
  - job: Analyze
    steps:
    - task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1
      inputs:
        languages: 'javascript'
        loglevel: '3'
        configfilepath: '$(build.sourcesDirectory)/.azuredevops/customcodeql/customconfig.yaml'

    - task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Autobuild@1
      displayName: 'Advanced Security Autobuild'

    - task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Analyze@1   

Am I missing something in the todos.ql, metadata or something ? I have changes the filter and include in the customconfig.yaml. Tried with or without them.

Hi there, may I know your custom query is pushed to the branch, the code from which is scanned by this pipeline?

@AlvinZhao-MSFT On the Linux build agent the log says: Starting: Checkout big-javascriptrepo@feature/CQL-HomeMade to s is made . Afaik I know that is then that code base on  Linux server that is scanned. But the scanning does not start since I get the error on the init task AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1 . Or did I misunderstand your question?

I think your current file structure is correct and I can reproduce the issue based on your description. But I am not sure how to modify the query. May I know if the scan works in your local environment with CodeQL CLI?

I asked copilot and it thinks, even when I asked it to double check, that the uses key should not be indented even though, to the casual YAML hacker, it looks right because it matches the formatting under query-filters which copilot says is correct. In other words, name and uses should be at the same indentation level.
Let me know if this works and I can add it as an answer along with the long explanation from co-pilot.

btw, Hi Patrik! :D  One thing that bothers me, without being familar with codeql, is the paths. What is the path relative to, the working directory or the config file? Have you tried putting the  build.sourcesdirectory variable into the path in the customconfig.yaml file? It does sounds like it should be finding it, since you don't get the error - unless the indent I mention above got introduced after so the uses isn't even being noticed anymore. Although Alvin reproduces the behaviour with the right indentation and his paths should cause file not found if the relativeness is an issue...

@housten I corrected the intendation in my code example. It was just bad copy paste.

Have you tried putting the build.sourcesdirectory variable into the path in the customconfig.yaml file?
I am not sure I can do that. Since the customconfig.yaml is for for codeql engine. The relative path if from the root already.  But I do not think there is a problem with finding the todo code query since it gives an error when the path is wrong.


Hi @PatrikLindström, Hope everything goes well since our last conversions. Having discussed internally, we suggest adding the qlpack to run code scan with a single custom query. It is not included in the current document indeed, which has caused some confusions. The engineering group have noticed it and we appreciate your time and efforts to report this issue to the Developer Community. As for now, would you please try the steps in my updated answer below? Hope it works for you as well. Thank you so much again for the insights and sharing. Have a nice weekend.

tl;dr add qlpack.yml definition and a extra string column to todo.ql query.
In the same directory that the todo.ql query is add a yaml file eg called
qlpack.yml. In this file add the following:
version: 1.0.1
dependencies:
  codeql/javascript-all: "*"
  codeql/javascript-queries: "*"

I also had to add an extra column in the todo select query. Else it would fail.  Here I am just adding foobar ¯_(ツ)_/¯ . But you should of course add something more useful. You can eg add templates that takes data from the query. See example here for placeholders.
/**
 * @id js/javascript/todocomment
 * @name TODO_comments
 * @description Finds comments containing the word TODO
 * @kind problem
 * @problem.severity recommendation
 * @tags comment
 *       TODO
 */
import javascript

from Comment c
where c.getText().regexpMatch("(?si).*\\bTODO\\b.*")
select c,"foobar"

This answer is based on the developercommunity ticket solution
and meetings with GitHub Adv Security engineers.

Update
Indeed, it is not mentioned in Microsoft document, but we can resolve the issue by adding a qlpack.yml file in the same directory as todos.ql with the contents below. And the pipeline succeeded in initializing the CodeQL DB and reporting the issue detected by this custom query.
qlpack.yml
version: 1.0.1
dependencies:
  codeql/javascript-all: "*"
  codeql/javascript-queries: "*"





I can reproduce the same issue with the simplified CodeQL query, configuration and pipeline definition below.
/.azuredevops/customcodeql/todos.ql (with the contents copied from github/codeql; also tested with some other queries but no luck.)
/**
 * @id js/examples/todocomment
 * @name TODO comments
 * @description Finds comments containing the word TODO
 * @kind problem
 * @problem.severity recommendation
 * @tags comment
 *       TODO
 */

import javascript

from Comment c
where c.getText().regexpMatch("(?si).*\\bTODO\\b.*")
select c, "TODO comments indicate that the code may not be complete."

/.azuredevops/customcodeql/customconfig.yml
name: "Run custom queries"

# When using a configuration file, if you do not disable default queries,
# then the default CodeQL queries in the `code-scanning` query suite will also execute upon analysis.
disable-default-queries: true

# To reference local queries saved to your repository,
# the path must start with `./` followed by the path to the custom query or queries.
# Names for each query referenced is optional.
queries:
  - uses: ./.azuredevops/customcodeql/todos.ql

JSCodeQL.yml
steps:
- task: AdvancedSecurity-Codeql-Init@1
  inputs:
    languages: 'javascript'
    loglevel: '2'
    configfilepath: '$(build.sourcesDirectory)/.azuredevops/customcodeql/customconfig.yml'


Besides, I also checked the Query file metadata and alert message stly guide, the query file should be correct.
For this issue and your requirment to run a custom javascript CodeQL query for code scanning, you may report the problem with the findings in Developer Community - Azure DevOps, where the support team can engage the engineering group for further assistance and insights.

I have followed your advice @Alvin Zhao and reported it  to the Azure DevOps Dev Community at the link you provided. Also gave link back to this sso question.  Thanks for your help and support.

Hi @PatrikLindström, Appreciate your time and efforts. Have a nice weekend ahead.

Link to my developer community ticket, it is in triage mode now. Sent to the engineering team : https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Custom-CodeQL-query-in-Azure-DevOps-in-y/10665807

Thanks a lot for taking time to share the update.

Besides maybe some strange indentation in the yaml file (also from msft documentation) that I see housten commented about an alternative solution might be to package this as a ql pack and referencing that in the init step.
What you are doing should work but personally I like the more modular approach of creating ql packs better because it makes it easier to run the queries and model packs in a more standardized way. This for example makes it possible to run the queries locally on the dev machine or other CI/CD solutions with minimal effort.
This is what I usually do and have it working when running scans at for example Jenkins.

The error was reproducible after resolving the indentation syntax issues. A ql pack is an optional workaround and how to run a single custom query will be discussed in this DC thread. https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/Custom-CodeQL-query-in-Azure-DevOps-in-y/10665807
